# Can I put multiple playground files into one Xcode workbook?

Tags: swift, xcode, xcplayground

I am using Xcode Playgrounds to make tutorials about Swift.  I was wondering, can I put multiple playground files into one Xcode workbook?  I want one workbook with multiple playground tutorials in it.

Comment: You can add multiple source files in a playground yes, not sure about workbook?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can right click on your top level file and select the "New Playground Page" button, which will give you a separate page.

[image: new page]

The below image shows the new page created after you click that button. "Untitled Page" is the initial page, and "Untitled Page 2" is the new page.

[image: new page]

Comment: Thanks for the help, That works!  Ok, now I would like to make links to topics within my playgrounds.  So instead of going [Next] (@next) which brings me to the next page, can I do the same but send me to a topic within that same page?  Basically, I want to go back to a class and add code for additional properties or functions.  Say, that I am further along in the tutorial and want to quickly link back to the top...

Answer (score 3):

You can create either `Empty Project` or `Workspace` to manage your multiple playground files under one roof.

**1. Empty Project:**

- `File -> New -> Project`
- Choose `Other` and Select `Empty`

[image]

- Create/Add Your Playground files to the workspace by right clicking on the `Project Navigator`

[image]

**2. Workspace:**

- `File -> New -> Workspace`

[image: New Workspace Option]

- Create/Add Your Playground files to the workspace by right clicking on the `Project Navigator`

[image]